# How do I make a user-specific database in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql

so what I'm trying to do is make a user-specific dataset and show the data only to the user. You can think of social media. The layout is all the same, but what is shows is very much personalized to the user. I'm trying to do this with Django and PostgreSQL, but I have no idea on how to do this.
Btw I'm a beginner, I've only took a few Django classes. So if there is any further knowledge that I have to learn, please let me know.

I would very much appreciate your help or advice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i give link you see and follow it if any error let me know

you need to change in `settings.py` of you main project in database section
i give change not it

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'crmeasyDB',
        'USER': '<user name of your database>',
        'PASSWORD': 'warning this is where you need to put your password',
        'HOST': '/tmp',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

link : [database setting](https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/configure-the-database/)

if you got error let me know

Answer (score 1):

You may want multi-tenant architecture so each of your users' data will be managed on a separate postgres schema.
Check out: https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas
You may need to make a custom Middleware for tenant identification which is also very precisely mentioned in docs.